# Adding custom baucis routes to its generated swagger api

Tags: rest, express, middleware, swagger, baucis

When we create our apps, we usually add our own routes.
So using the baucis.rest i added some custom routes like example:

```
var controller = baucis.rest( {
     singular: 'User'
} );
controller.put('/myroute/:id', function(req,res,done){
    //doing something
})
```

My app runs and using the swagger ui i can see the operations about users.

```
GET   /Users/{id}                  description
PUT   /Users/{id}                  description 
......
```

I would like to add my "/myroute/:id' to the generated swagger api.

```
PUT   /Users/myroute/{id}          description
```

Does anyone know how to do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v0.9.0 , you can modify the swagger definitions directly.  It's purely cosmetic, only altering the swagger documentation, not any other functionality.

For example:

```
var controller = baucis.rest('User');
controller.swagger.apis.push({
  'path': '/Users/myroute/{id}',
  'description': 'Myroute custom description.',
  'operations': [
    {
      'httpMethod': 'PUT',
      'nickname': 'putSomethingCustom',
      'responseClass': 'User',
      'summary': 'Something custom.'
    }
  ]
})
```

`controller.swagger.models` is also exposed.

Comment: Wow thanks! @wprl :D much help.  So before i got this answer, i made changes to my code,  added hooks to schema so that i don't need to change the swagger.